# Laravel Forge/Envoyer using old releases since upgrading to 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I am experiencing very strange behavior since upgrading to `Laravel 5.5`, where the site will continue to show an old release after successfully deploying with `Envoyer`.

The `current` folder is correctly set to the newest release, however the site still shows the old release.

If the old release folder is manually deleted, or gets deleted via deploying enough times, the entire site will break, and this shows up:

```
Warning: include(/home/forge/sitefoo.com/envoyer/releases/20180130124512/vendor/composer/../vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Exception/InvalidPathException.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/forge/sitefoo.com/envoyer/releases/20180130124512/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/home/forge/sitefoo.com/envoyer/releases/20180130124512/vendor/composer/../vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Exception/InvalidPathException.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/forge/sitefoo.com/envoyer/releases/20180130124512/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444

Warning: include(/home/forge/sitefoo.com/envoyer/releases/20180130124512/vendor/composer/../symfony/debug/Exception/FatalThrowableError.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/forge/sitefoo.com/envoyer/releases/20180130124512/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/home/forge/sitefoo.com/envoyer/releases/20180130124512/vendor/composer/../symfony/debug/Exception/FatalThrowableError.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/forge/sitefoo.com/envoyer/releases/20180130124512/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError' not found in /home/forge/sitefoo.com/envoyer/releases/20180130124512/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:122 Stack trace: #0 /home/forge/sitefoo.com/envoyer/releases/20180130124512/public/index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #1 {main} thrown in /home/forge/sitefoo.com/envoyer/releases/20180130124512/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php on line 122
```

Once you restart the server after deleting the old folder, everything will go back to normal and the correct release will be used.

Does anyone have any ideas on what's going wrong or how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Are you restarting  php-fpm after each release?

Comment: According to the Envoyer deployment logs, it appears that yes, it is reloading PHP-FPM (with no error)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution to this problem was updating the server's PHP version in `Envoyer`.

After updating to `Laravel 5.5`, the server was also updated to `PHP 7.2`. This was never set in the `Envoyer` server's settings, and therefore was causing issues, probably using the old `PHP-FPM` version.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read this appears to be related to the queue listener, specifically when it's not running as a daemon. The fix appears to be setting up the queue processor in Forge as a daemon.

Additionally change the worker recipe to clear the cache before the queue restarts:

```
// change php version to yours
sudo service php7.1-fpm reload
// clear cache
php artisan queue:restart
```